# How to extend number of decimals that show

Tags: python, function, numpy, latitude-longitude

I have this code that I need to change to pass the below assert test:

```
def degrees_to_dms(degrees_fraction):
    ''' Convert degrees to degree, minute, second 3-tuples'''
    degrees = int(degrees_fraction)
    minutes = abs(degrees_fraction - degrees) * 60.0
    seconds = np.round((degrees_fraction - degrees - minutes/60.0) * 3600.0, 2)
    return (degrees, abs(minutes), abs(seconds))


def dms_to_degrees(d,m,s):
    ''' Convert degrees, minutes, seconds to fractional degrees'''
    return float(d)+float(m/60.00)+float(s/3600.00)
```

And it needs to pass this assert test:

```
assert dms_to_degrees(*degrees_to_dms(42.2833333333)) == 42.28333333333333
```

The only difference is that there are four more 3's in the expected outcome. In iterating through each step of the process, it looks like the addition of float(d) with float(m/60.00) in dms_to_degrees leads to a rounding of the decimal places. I'd like to make it so that it outputs those extra 3's. I also noticed that m/60 = 0.2833333332999999, so I don't know why they expect the 2999999 to become all 3's anyways. But maybe there is a different approach needed altogether.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue of numbers of decimals shown in the output but a normal floating point issue.

You can show more decimals in the output by formatting:

```
print(f'{dms_to_degrees(*degrees_to_dms(42.2833333333)):.50f}')
# 42.28333333329999987881819834001362323760986328125000
```

Comparison of floating point numbers is pointless and not portable. You should use [isclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for comparing floats:

```
assert np.isclose(dms_to_degrees(*degrees_to_dms(42.2833333333)) , 42.28333333333333)
```

---

**Update** If you can't change the test you can fix `degrees_to_dms` by rounding the minutes to a whole number if the value is very close to an integer (smaller then some epsilon of say 1e-6):

```
def degrees_to_dms(degrees_fraction):
    ''' Convert degrees to degree, minute, second 3-tuples'''
    degrees = int(degrees_fraction)
    minutes = abs(degrees_fraction - degrees) * 60.0
    if (abs(minutes - round(minutes)) < 1e-6):
        minutes = round(minutes)
    seconds = np.round((degrees_fraction - degrees - minutes/60.0) * 3600.0, 2)
    return (degrees, abs(minutes), abs(seconds))
```

In my opinion, however, this is just a trick to make an ill-designed test case pass. See for instance the output of `42.2833333333` at https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/dms-decimal: they show `42° 16' 59.9982"` instead of `42° 17' 0.0"`.

Comment: I don't think they have a way of changing the assert. I think there is a way to do float math here that passes the assert

Comment: @MegaIng: you're probably right, but I don't think there a reasonable change in the float math to pass the assert, as `42.28333333333333` (the right hand side) can't be represented as a finite floating point number, so the whole effort is rather pointless in my opinion

Comment: Ok, I take that back. The assert is simply broken `42.2833333333 != 42.28333333333333`

Comment: Thanks all. So how should I approach it then? Megalng is right in that I cannot change the assert.

Comment: @Julien: please see my updated answer